# ¿Como puedo arreglar el siguiente error? me marca 500 server internal error

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, postgresql, flask

A continuacion adjunto codigo de mi back: Aqui hago la importacion de los Cors para los permisos necesarios que requiere la app, al correr mi front y el back e ir a la parte de registarse de mi front y hacer un registro marca este error, Esta es la parte de lo que les hablo, espero me puedan ayudar, puedo pasar el link de mi repositorio si desean [image]

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app) # Agregar esta línea para permitir solicitudes CORS
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 
'postgresql://postgres:sebas2013@localhost/flasksql' # URL de la base de datos
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.secret_key = 'secret string'
db = SQLAlchemy(app) # instancia de la base de datos



class User(db.Model): # modelo de la tabla de usuarios
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
password = db.Column(db.String(50))
email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

def __init__(self, username, password, email):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.email = email

def __repr__(self):
    return f'<User {self.username}>'

with app.app_context():
db.create_all() # crea la tabla de usuarios si no existe

@app.route("/members")
@cross_origin(origin='*')
def members():
return {"members": ["Member1", "Member2", "Member3"]}

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='*')
def login():
username = request.form['username']
password = request.form['password']
if username == 'usuario' and password == 'contraseña':
    return jsonify({'message': 'Inicio de sesión exitoso'}), 200
else:
    return jsonify({'message': 'Credenciales inválidas'}), 401

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='*')
def register():
username = request.json['username']
password = request.json['password']
email = request.json['email']
user = User(username, password, email)
db.session.add(user) # agrega el usuario a la base de datos
db.session.commit() # guarda los cambios en la base de datos
response = {
    'message': 'Registro exitoso',
    'data': {
        'username': username,
        'email': email
    }
}
return jsonify(response), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Despues este es mi codigo que tengo en el front de la pagina registrarse:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const RegistroForm = () => {
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [error, setError] = useState('');
const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

try {
  setLoading(true); // Mostrar animación de carga

  // Enviar solicitud de registro al backend
  const response = await axios.post('/register', {
    username,
    password,
    email
  });

  setLoading(false); // Ocultar animación de carga

  // Manejar la respuesta del backend
  const { message, data } = response.data;
  setSuccess(true);
  setError('');
  console.log(message, data);

} catch (error) {
  setLoading(false); // Ocultar animación de carga

  // Manejar errores de la solicitud
  setError('Error en el registro');
  console.error(error);
}
};

  return (
  <div
  style={{
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: '100vh',
  }}
>
  <h1 style={{ fontSize: '36px', marginBottom: '24px' }}>Regístrate  </h1> {/* Título 
  grande "Regístrate" */}
  <form
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    style={{
      maxWidth: '300px',
      padding: '24px',
      backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
      borderRadius: '10px',
    }}
  >
    {success && <p style={{ color: 'green' }}>Registro exitoso</p>}
    {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</p>}
    {loading && <p>Cargando...</p>}
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Nombre de usuario"
      value={username}
      onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
      style={{
        marginBottom: '12px',
        borderRadius: '25px',
        padding: '12px',
        fontSize: '18px',
        border: '2px solid #7620ff', // Color de borde #7620ff
      }}
    />
    <input
      type="password"
      placeholder="Contraseña"
      value={password}
      onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      style={{
        marginBottom: '12px',
        borderRadius: '25px',
        padding: '12px',
        fontSize: '18px',
        border: '2px solid #7620ff', // Color de borde #7620ff
      }}
    />
    <input
      type="email"
      placeholder="Correo electrónico"
      value={email}
      onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      style={{
        marginBottom: '12px',
        borderRadius: '25px',
        padding: '12px',
        fontSize: '18px',
        border: '2px solid #7620ff', // Color de borde #7620ff
      }}
    />
    <button
      type="submit"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        color: 'white',
        borderRadius: '30px',
        padding: '12px 29px',
        border: 'none',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        transition: 'background-color 0.3s ease-in-out',
        alignSelf: 'center', // Centrar el botón verticalmente
      }}
      onMouseEnter={(e) => e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#7620ff'}
      onMouseLeave={(e) => e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'gray'}
    >
      Registrarse
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
);
};

export default RegistroForm;
```

Necesito saber porque marca este error, tengo cors instalados no se que me hace falta, espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba el request con Postman para empezar a ver donde está el problema.